# работа с циклами и списками

Tags: python, list, циклы

помогите пожалуйста, как организовать программу так, чтобы она удаляла с каждым разом всё больше значений? у меня прога прогоняет, например, ABCDEF типо сначала A удалит, вернёт список, потом B, возвращает, потом С... и так по кругу.
Я не понимаю как заставить её работать так, чтоб после первого цикла она начал удалять AB, AC, AD... потом BA, BC, ну вы поняли. Я не понимаю как всучить сюда ещё один цикл, и куда переставить возврат строки.
помогите, извините что много букв

```
def sga235():
    global n
    global sum
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if i != 0:
            del n[i]
        for j in range(len(n)):
            del n[j]
            s1 = ''.join(n)
            if s1 == s1[::-1]:
                sum += 1
            n = list(s)
s = input()
sum = 0
n = list(s)
for i in range(1, len(n) + 1):
    for j in range(i):
        sga235()
print(sum)
```

выше вы видите мою попытку заставить код работать по моему, но ответ всё неутешительный, т. к. он плюсует в счётчик всё одно и то же

а, да, программа действует так: прогоняет некую строку, удаляет из неё значение, и если оставшееся слово палиндром, то прибавляет в счётчик

я пробовал на значении HEIHEH, должно выводить 22
вот в принципе с чего начинал:

```
def sga235():
    global n
    global sum
    for i in range(len(n)):
        del n[i]
        s1 = ''.join(n)
        if s1 == s1[::-1]:
            sum += 1
        n = list(s)

s = input()
sum = 1
n = list(s)
for i in range(1, len(n) + 1):
    for j in range(i):
        sga235()
print(sum)
```

выше я пытался всунуть ещё один цикл, но как видите, не получилось.

Comment: справа ссылки примерно на десять вопросов с почти идентичным названием. Они уже изучены и там нет решения?

Comment: здравствуйте! изучил, вроде бы вообще не то

Comment: `sum` - это функция питона, не нужно перекрывать её именем вашей переменной

Comment: itertools.combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно просто задача делается при помощи itertools.combinations

```
import itertools

string = 'HEIHEH'
cnt = 0

i = len(string)
while i:
    for s in itertools.combinations(string, i):
        if s == s[::-1]:
            cnt += 1
    i -= 1
print(cnt)   # 22
```

---

Трехстрочник для любителей однострочников

```
print(sum(s == s[::-1] \
      for i in range(1, len(string)+1) \
      for s in itertools.combinations(string, i)))
```